# how to pass a parameter from JQUERY to PHP in order to update a session variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass a selection/value from a dropdown menu which was dynamically created to php file and store it in a session variable, but the php is not getting any parameter.
This is my code in the Jquery file:

```
$('#fgdesignation').change(function ()
            {
                var project =$("#fgdesignation option::selected").text();
                var url='backend.php';
             // alert(project);
            $.post(url, {fgdname : project});

        });
```

and this is the php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['fgdname'])) {
    $fgdname= $_POST['fgdname'];
    $_SESSION['fgdname']=$fgdname;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: POST it with ajax to a php endpoint, for example post it to post.php

Comment: Does your alert statement return a value?

Comment: Did you debug the request to make sure that 1) parameters are being sent, and 2) a response comes back (i.e., the php file doesn't throw an error and fail.

Comment: `option::selected` should be `option:selected`

Comment: Actually, `$("#fgdesignation option::selected")` should probably be `$("#fgdesignation").val()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#fgdesignation').change(function () {
    var project = $("#fgdesignation").filter(':selected').val();
    var url = 'backend.php';
    // alert(project);
    $.post(url, {
        fgdname: project
    });
});
```

Off hand, I saw that you were using `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Uncomment your `alert()` and see if there is  value being returned

**EDIT** I did `$("#fgdesignation").filter(':selected').val();` assuming: `<select id="fgdesignation'>`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add

```
session_start()
```

at the top of your PHP file. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#fgdesignation').change(function ()
            {
                var project =$("#fgdesignation option:selected").val();
                var url='backend.php';
             // alert(project);
            $.post(url, {fgdname : project}, function(response){alert(response);});

        });
```

You were using `.text()` instead of `.val()`, which returns the value of the currently selected option, as well as having '::' as your selector when you only needed one.

And in your PHP file:

```
session_start(); // Important if you're not already doing it!
if(isset($_POST['fgdname'])) {
    $fgdname= $_POST['fgdname'];
    $_SESSION['fgdname']=$fgdname;
    echo $fgdname;
}
```

If all goes to plan you should have an alert box with the value of what you selected in the select box and have it present in the session array. Give it a go.